# Вообще — обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация

«...которые находят гармонию с животными, а другие, вообще, видят единственный выход из ситуации — смерть.»

Нужны ли запятые?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае "вообще" (со значением "в целом") является **наречием и не обособляется**, также при такой структуре предложения  нет интонационного выделения. В роли необособленного обстоятельства это слово встречается чаще.

Обособленный вариант для сравнения: **Вообще,** одинаковых работ за 12 лет нашего существования не было. Это **вводное слово** со значением "вообще говоря".

Comment: >>  *(со значением "в целом")* Не "в целом" а "вовсе".

Comment: Из справочника: в целом, в общем; совсем,  при всех условиях).

Answer (score 0):

Если  слово "вообще" было бы вводным словом, то тогда да, запятая была бы здесь уместна: А вообще, он хороший парень. В данном случае - как Вам уже сообщили из предыдущего ответа - "вообще" употреблено в значении "в целом".  "В целом" не является вводным словом: это - обстоятельство, - а значит запятая перед ним, после него или посередине не ставится.